# How to plot different subplots in terms of different files located in one directory?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I’ve got a directory with 10 different txt-files. Every txt-file contains one x-row and one y-row, the structure of the files is always the same, but the values are different from each other. I want to plot multiple subplots (10 in total, **only one figure**!), and each subplot should represent exactly one file. In other words, at the end I would like to have ten different plots, which are in accordance with the txt-files. 
My first approach is as follows:

```
%matplotlib inline
import glob
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_path = 'C:\\Users\\MyPath'

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=2, figsize=(8, 6))
fig.tight_layout()

files = glob.glob(data_path+'/*.txt')

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    for row in range(5):
        for col in range(2):
            ax[row][col].plot(df['time'], df['signal'], c='green')
```

The problem in my code is that all files are plotted in every subplot, see example: 
[image: Example subplots]
It loops over the entire files before plotting them, but it should stop at every new file… How can I solve the problem, so that only one specific file is “represented” in each subplot? 
I would be grateful for any advice. Please keep in mind that I'm not a professional. Thanks for the help already in advance.

Comment: are you able to post sample data please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ax` is a numpy ndarray of Axes - flatten it and iterate over it with the files.

```
...
for axn,file in zip(ax.flatten(),files):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    axn.plot(df['time'], df['signal'], c='green')
```

Or:

```
...
for axn,file in zip(ax.flatten(),files):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df.plot(x='time', y='signal', ax=axn, c='green')
```

---

https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html